# .NET IO: Can I force a BinaryWriter (or a FileStream) to always flush to disk?

Tags: .net, io

I need behaviour similar to Java's [`RandomAccessFile(path, "rws")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#mode) method, namely flushing data to disk as soon as it is written to the file.

I lean towards using [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.IO.BINARYWRITER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) for my purposes, but it doesn't have a way to specify the flushing behaviour.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BinaryWriter` is not `sealed`, and all of the `Write` methods are `virtual`. You could override them and add a call to `Flush`, for example:

```
public override void Write(byte value)
{
    base.Write(value);
    Flush(); // which is just: this.OutStream.Flush();
}
```

However! In most cases this would be ***really bad*** for performance. I don't recommend it.

If you are using a `StreamWriter` or similar, then just set `AutoFlush` to `true`; job done; but again - this could really hurt performance.

Comment: I never knew about AutoFlush, that's really helpful, +1!

Comment: I looked at AutoFlush (it's referenced in the BinaryWriter.Flush() documentation!), but StreamWriter is text-based (encodings and all), while I need something binary-based...

Comment: Regarding the overriding of BinaryWriter methods, I thought about it. I was just hoping something similar had already been done :)

Comment: By the way, how does the call to BW.Flush() stand in regard to Filestream.Flush() *not actually flushing to disk*? (i.e. it doesn't call Win32 FlushFileBuffers)? The new (.NET 4.0+) FileStream.Flush(true) method may be of assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing an extension method as a wrapper:

```
public static class MyBinaryWriterExtensions {
  public static void WriteAndFlush(this BinaryWriter writer, byte[] data) {
     writer.Write(data);
     // Slow! Disk access is at least 10 ms! (for a fast disk)
     writer.Flush();
  }
}
```

This would be called like this:

```
BinaryWriter bw = ... // Getting your writer somehow
byte[] data = ... // your data
bw.WriteAndFlush(data); // Will write and flush!
```

Or are you in need of some kind of atomicity?

Comment: if you are using `StreamWriter`, an easier approach would be to set `AutoFlush` to `true`.

Comment: @MarcGravell That is totally correct, I planned on writing BinaryWriter though :) Editing..

Answer (score 0):

You can put every writer into 'using' which will Dispose() it at the end

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            writer.Write(1.250F);
            writer.Write(@"c:\Temp");
            writer.Write(10);
            writer.Write(true);
        }
```

For the text you can use `File.WriteAllText` function which doesn't need flush at all

Comment: "which will mark it for garbage collector" - `using` has absolutely **nothing** to do with the garbage collector. `using` just means it will call `IDisposable.Dispose()` at the end of the block, if the variable is non-null.

Comment: @MarcGravell exactly, ...which will mark it as ready for collect for garbage collector

Comment: Exactly not. It explicitly does **not** mark it as ready for the garbage collector. If you keep a reference to `writer`, it will still never be collected. Garbage collection will behave 100% identically whether or not you use `using`. The two things are completely unrelated at the technical level (although at the *human* level, they seem to do similar things, but one is deterministic, the other is non-deterministic). There is **no such thing** as marking an object as "ready to collect". That concept *does not exist*.

Comment: @MarcGravell as you can't keep a reference to the writer after you exited this using (in my example) writer will be marked as ready to collect. If you say it's impossible to mark it for collection or temporarily prevent it's collection, you can read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx . I simplified my answer for Java-guy who probably doesn't know about usings, but maybe you are right, I've simplified it too much.

Comment: The garbage collector itself marks objects so that it **doesn't** collect them. As Marc said.. completely unrelated.

Comment: @VladL "Potentially eligible for collection" and "being marked" are completely separate concepts.

Comment: @Vlad I'm a .NET guy actually :)

Answer (score 0):

See also the WriteThrough option, which you can provide when creating a file stream. It causes your stream to skip all OS-level buffering.  I *think* however, that there is still buffering within the stream, at the size specified in the stream's constructor (or 4k if not specified). So I *think* that with WriteThrough the stream object itself buffers until the specified buffer size is full, and then immediately writes through to the underlying storage.

Ayende has a write-up here: https://ayende.com/blog/163073/file-i-o-flush-or-writethrough